# Calculate the probability of rolling a 6 from a randomly selected die

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have a box of dice that contains a 4-sided die, a 6-sided die, an
8-sided die, a 12-sided die, and a 20-sided die. If you have ever played
Dungeons & Dragons, you know what I am talking about.

Suppose I select a die from the box at random, roll it, and get a 6. What is
the probability that I rolled each die?

Comment: What have you tried?  The probability you rolled the four sided die is zero.  The title does not match the question in the body.

Comment: You have tagged the question as [tag:bayes-theorem], so you clearly think that it's relevant. Have you tried using it? If not, do so and report back to us. If you have, tell us in details what didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(\text{rolled a $k$-sided die } | \text{ rolled a 6}) = \dfrac{P(\text{rolled a 6 } | \text{ rolled a $k$-sided die}) \cdot P(\text{rolled a $k$-sided die})}{P(\text{rolled a 6})}$$

And $P(\text{rolled a 6}) = \dfrac{1}{5}\left(0 +\dfrac{1}{6} +\dfrac{1}{8} +\dfrac{1}{12} +\dfrac{1}{20} \right) = \dfrac{17}{200}$, meaning:

$$P(\text{rolled a $k$-sided die } | \text{ rolled a 6}) = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{k} \cdot [k \geq 6]\right) \cdot \dfrac{1}{5}}{\dfrac{17}{200}} = \dfrac{40}{17k} \cdot [k \geq 6]$$

Where $[x]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), which evaluates to $1$ if $x$ is true, and $0$ if $x$ is false.